# Google Webmaster Tools shows huge dip, not consistent with real world

Tags: google-search-console

Here is Webmaster Tools and Google Analytics.

[image]
[image]

The Analytics one is correct (because I would know if my traffic dropped 90%... the phone would stop ringing.

Is GWT smoking crack? Have you seen this before? Can this be fixed?

Comment: Look fine to me, Impressions are only how often keywords of your pages appear in the results... If you have 100,000 impressions but on page 10 you would not generate many clicks nor would you lose page views if that keyword dropped of the face of the earth. Also your comparing page views to impressions which isn't a correct way of doing it... GWT measures clicks of Google, if you have visitors coming from Bing, Direct Traffic these will appear in Google Anaytics only...  GWT is only Search Results, Analytics looks at all traffic. The stats that you should consider important is unique visitors.

Comment: if unique visitors drops then you have a problem otherwise you should consider it incorrect data, GWT is renowned for giving false data, it happens but not saying this is the case.. with the given information it looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could a a shift from Google sending traffic to your site with a `www` (`www.example.com`) to Google sending traffic to your site without a `www` (`example.com`).  When you have only `www.example.com` registered in webmaster tools, it won't show you activity on your base domain.  Google Analytics would still show all the traffic because th e tracking code would still be getting triggered.

Ensure that you have your site registered twice in Google Webmaster Tools.  Register once with the `www` and once without and see if you can find the missing traffic.

Comment: Thanks, what you are saying did happen. The odd thing is that my new www. domain also shows the same drop off.